# How do you compile all classes in a package from the command line?

Tags: java, compilation, package

I have three separate class files in a package called stacks. How can I (recursively?) compile every class so I don't always have to type the following:

```
javac stacks/Node.java stacks/LinkedList.java stacks/LLTestCase01.java
```

There will be more classes added so I don't want to keep expanding this compile list.

Comment: might try `-sourcepath .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `javac stacks/*.java`. That's all you need.